# compile error during build when initialize an object from static library

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, static-libraries, objectinstantiation

I have the following compile error when try to create and initialize an object in Data parser class. The code is

```
Component *component=[[Component alloc] initWithInputComObjects:inputComObjects withOutputComObjects:outputComObjects];
```

where `initWithInputComObjects:inputComObjects:withOutputComObjects:outputComObjects` is a method inside the .m file in the library

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Desktop/KNXComfort/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/admin/Desktop/KNXComfort/KNXComfort/libKNXCommuncationLib.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/admin/Desktop/KNXComfort/KNXComfort/libKNXCommuncationLib.a (3 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Channel", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DataParser.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ComObject", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DataParser.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Component", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DataParser.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Device", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DataParser.o
>        (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_DevicesCollectionViewController, _OBJC_CLASS_$_DevicesCollectionViewCell )
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386

You are trying to build for the i386 processor but the library you are trying to use wasn't built to support that architecture.

You either need to remove i386 from your build (build for a device) or rebuild the library to include support for i386.